# Difference between "I don't believe it." and "I can't believe it."

Tags: differences

What is the difference between ***I don't believe it.*** and ***I can't believe it.***?

For example,

> A: I've heard John got that job.
>
> B:"I don't believe it." or "I can't believe it."

Comment: Good question. I don't believe it's a duplicate. I can't believe it hasn't been asked yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there seems to be a difference, in fact, most times the two expressions are interchangeable in use. Or so say most natives in the language forums. Here is an [interesting post](https://www.italki.com/post/question-304037):

> There is very little difference between the two statements. To hair split, one can say '***I don't believe this***' is an ***absolute rejection*** while '***I can't believe this***' is less absolute and has a connotation of ***disbelief*** in something one has read or seen. 
> NB ***The intonation and stress when spoken is important and gives a guide to what the speaker means**.*

I think the NB is spot on. You can use both expressions in a situation, but it is the intonation that will give it meaning and nuance. You can trust [Victor Meldrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Foot_in_the_Grave) from [*One Foot in the Grave*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVAX166QwrU)! <sub>*See video with **plenty of intonations** in the link! And try not to laugh!*</sub>

***I don't believe it*** is defined as

> An expression of *surprise* or *incredulity*, possibly *bordering on vexation.*
>
> - ***I don't believe it***—I have the winning lottery ticket!
> - So you came crawling back to us after all. ***I don't believe it***. ([FreeDict](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+don%27t+believe+it!))

The same dictionary says about ***I can't believe it/that/this***

> This information is so *shocking* or *implausible* as to be ***unbelievable***.
>
> - A: "Did you hear that Amanda got the promotion?" 
>   B: "Yep, and ***I can't believe it***. I know I'm more qualified for it than she is!"
> - Are they really closing McCauley's after 40 years? ***I can't believe it!*** ([FreeDict](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+can%27t+believe+it!))

I think trying to differentiate the two phrases by focusing on the difference between *don't* and *can't* won't get us too far.

[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/can-t-don-t-believe-it) goes as far to conisder them as two versions of the same phrase:

> *can’t/don’t believe it*
>
> - used for emphasizing that you are extremely surprised or shocked
>   used when something annoys you

You will find [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do%20not%20believe%20it%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Ccannot%20believe%20it%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Cdo%20not%20believe%20it%3Aeng_us_2019%2Ccannot%20believe%20it%3Aeng_us_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20believe%20it%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20believe%20it%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20believe%20it%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20believe%20it%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20believe%20it%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20believe%20it%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20believe%20it%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20believe%20it%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0) interesting: On both sides of the ocean, ***I don't believe it*** is far more common.

PS: As a matter of fact, I think that gestures and mimics are just as important as intonation in what one means by this expression!

[image]

Comment: "[I Can't Believe It's Not Butter!](https://www.icantbelieveitsnotbutter.com/en)" is a successful brand name. I doubt "I Don't Believe It's Not Butter!" would have worked.

Comment: The OP's question is about _I don't/can't believe it._ Not about instances where _believe_ is followed by a clause.

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Comment: I think the difference in meaning conveyed by intonation is _very_ important here — so much that it should probably be at the top of your answer rather than in the middle. Also, context!

Comment: @mattdm Thanks for the suggestion, I have edited. I am not sure by what you mean by context though...

Comment: Thank you everyone!